# Jackson failed to deserialization OneToMany relationship entity

Tags: java, json, jackson, json-deserialization, jackson2

I'm having a oneToMany reltionShip between two entities:

```
public class Product  {
  @JsonBackReference
  private List<ProductDetail> listProductDetail;
```

And

```
public class ProductDetail {
   @JsonManagedReference
   private Product product;
```

I'm trying to deserialize the entity ProductDetail but I'm always getting the following exception:

```
jackson can not handle managed/back reference 'defaultreference': back reference type (java.util.list) not compatible with managed type
```

I have tryed different json formats (including the product in the json message,removing this field) but always the same result.

Can anyone please explain to me what does this error means and how to resolve it without modifying my entities if possible (the entities are part of our datamodel component which is used by other colleagues)

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply,
I didn't use that annotation before,could you please add more details how to add it and why I'm getting that exception,I want to know why is jackson throwing that error?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could instead try and use [`@JsonIdentityInfo`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIdentityInfo.html) on the entities as:

```
public class Product  {
  @JsonIdentityInfo
  private List<ProductDetail> listProductDetail;

public class ProductDetail {
   @JsonIdentityInfo
   private Product product;
```

Comment: Thanks,
Is there a solution without modifying my entities as they are shared by other modules?
And can you help please why jackson is throwing that exception?

Comment: @Zizou Did you mean not even modifying annotations in the models/entities?

Comment: Yes,without modifying the annotations